# Excel - Sum of values in multiple columns

Tags: excel

```
apple   banana  apple
 52       12     35
 25       21     53
 44       65     41
```

How do I get the sum of all values in multiple columns that satisfy a condition (say looking for columns having apple as the header) and I can get the sum of all the values appearing under `apple` column. I need 250 as the answer. Is it possible to generate it using formulas? In other words, I look for headers containing `apple` and provide total of all the numbers that fall within the header.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=SUM(INDEX((A1:C1=E2)*A2:C4,))
```

[image]

As per your comments to find if the Word is in a longer string use:

```
=SUM(INDEX((ISNUMBER(SEARCH( E2,A1:C1)))*A2:C4,))
```

[image]

Comment: this also works without being entered as array-formula... interesting... :)

Comment: I found this technique a few weeks ago.

Comment: Awesome Scott! thanks What do I need to do if I want to perform the same calculation for all the columns that end with apple. Is it possible?

Comment: @JayDee Are they all in the same row?  Also, If not the same row are they the last cell with text?

Comment: Yes, Scott. they all appear in the same row as you see above. The only thing is that it ends with Apple. It could be something like "Nice Apple" in one column, another could be "Green Apple"...and so on.

Comment: Hi Scott, this worked like charm...super cool! really appreciate it.

Comment: Another challenge: sorry about that! What if one of the numbers (A2:C4) is a non-numeric character....say NA. The formula does not spit out the result. Can it be fixed?

Comment: The best way would be to deal with the formula that is returning the error.

Answer (score 3):

Sumproduct will do:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:C4*(A1:C1="apple"))
```

Going with Scotts layout for fruits including the keyword:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:C4*ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E2,A1:C1)))
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:C4*ISNUMBER(FIND(E2,A1:C1)))
```

`FIND` if case matters and `SEARCH` if not.
For excluding the keyword (for being somewhere in the names) simply replace `ISNUMBER` with `ISERROR`

**EDIT**:

When dealing with non-numeric values (such as text or errors) you can use this array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(A2:C4),A2:C4)*ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E2,A1:C1)))
```

> This is an array-formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>!

Comment: @JayDee I edited my answer to show how to deal with non-numerical values... this simply skips such cells ;)